# Twitter-Bootstrap Login in Oracle Apex Template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, oracle-apex

I am having trouble working out how to implement the twitter bootstrap framework into Oracle Apex Themes.

Currently I would love my Apex login page to look something like this:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/signin.html

However I am currently unable to find out where to edit the template to allow me to use the Bootstrap classes.

Within the Login Template, the Definition Header and Definition Body does not appear to allow me to manually change the classes of the login text boxes and the submit buttons.

How can I implement the bootstrap CSS classes into my login page?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just use the bootstrap classes in your markup? Could you provide a little more information?

Comment: The bootstrap classes in my markup does not appear to modify the objects, for example, I am trying to use 
the class "btn" for a button, instead of the default "button-default", it does not display the button formatting at all!

Comment: have you linked the bootstrap stylesheet into your page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you uploaded the CSS files to the shared components?

Also, If you go into Shared Components>Templates and filter for Pages you can add the CSS file to the Page template under Cascading Style Sheets.

I would imagine if you are really savvy it might be easier to make your own templates from scratch; however, I am not that good with APEX yet so I choose to modify my existing templates.